# achieving equal height columns with flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to build a layout which has two separate content groups: one on the left side and right side, with fixed width (20%/80%) for now. On each side, I am trying to arrange contents by using flexbox: left panel with `flex-direction: column` and right panel with `flex-direction: row wrap`. The number of contents on each side can be flexible. The panel with less contents should match the height of the other, 'taller' side.

So far, I was able to achieve the basic layout, as shown in this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/31v8jzu5/). However, my problem is that I cannot make the the 'shorter' panel to fill the height, even though I set the height to be 100%. In the given example, there is an empty space between 'C' div of left panel and 'Box7' div of the right panel. The html/css code is show below.

How could I fix this problem or is there nicer simpler layout solutions? Any help would be appreciated.

HTML

```
<div class='top'>
    <div class='left'>
        <div class='litem'>A</div>
        <div class='litem'>B</div>
        <div class='litem'>C</div>
    </div>
    <div class='right'>
        <div class='ritem'>Box 1</div>
        <div class='ritem'>Box 2</div>
        <div class='ritem'>Box 3</div>
        <div class='ritem'>Box 4</div>
        <div class='ritem'>Box 5</div>
        <div class='ritem'>Box 6</div>
        <div class='ritem'>Box 7</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
* { outline: 1px solid Grey; }

html {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: Cornsilk;
}

.top {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.left {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 20%;
    height: 100%;
}

.right {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 80%;
    height: 100%;
}

.litem, .ritem {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.litem { height: 50%; }
.ritem { height: 50%; width: 33.3%;}

.litem:nth-child(1) { background-color: Cyan; }
.litem:nth-child(2) { background-color: DarkCyan; }
.litem:nth-child(3) { background-color: DarkSeaGreen; }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you apply `height: 100%` to `html` and `body`, you limit the growth of the child elements to 100% of the screen.

In your code, your `.left` flex item is indeed stretching to `height: 100%`, as specified. Add a border around `.left` for an illustration: [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/31v8jzu5/2/)

If you remove all the fixed heights, you'll enable the flex container to stretch all flex items, per the default setting: `align-items: stretch` (the setting that creates equal height columns). [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/31v8jzu5/3/)

When you add `flex: 1` to the `.left` flex items (`.litem`), they then distribute all available space in the container evenly among themselves. [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/31v8jzu5/5/).

In a nutshell, when you use the `height` property you *override* `align-items: stretch`, the flex setting for equal height columns.

Comment: Thank you for great tips! One thing though, now I noticed that I can no longer control the height of the individual content Boxes. In other words, .litem, .ritem {height: 50%} doesn't work, compressing all the content boxes to the top. Any suggestion on this part?

Comment: Any type of `height` values you use in your `.litem` boxes (such as px, em or vh -- but not percentages) will work. Here are your boxes with 200px height. Equal height columns are maintained: https://jsfiddle.net/31v8jzu5/15/

Comment: Oh, I see. Then, it seems like that there is no way for me to auto control the box heights to fit the screen so that no scroll bar is shown?

Comment: Yay. It works really nicely. I learned a lot from your comments. Thanks a lot for the help! :)